# Fading Text in with Duration in SwiftUI

Tags: animation, swiftui, fadein

I have been using the following UIView extension for quite a while to fade text in and out.  I have been trying to figure out how to implement this with SwiftUI but so far haven't found anything that exactly addresses this for me.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
extension UIView {

   func fadeKey() {
      // Move our fade out code from earlier
      UIView.animate(withDuration: 3.0, delay: 2.0, options: UIView.AnimationOptions.curveEaseIn, animations: {
          self.alpha = 1.0 // Instead of a specific instance of, say, birdTypeLabel, we simply set [thisInstance] (ie, self)'s alpha
          }, completion: nil)
   }

    func fadeIn1() {
        // Move our fade out code from earlier
      UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.5, delay: 0.5, options: UIView.AnimationOptions.curveEaseIn, animations: {
            self.alpha = 1.0 // Instead of a specific instance of, say, birdTypeLabel, we simply set [thisInstance] (ie, self)'s alpha
            }, completion: nil)
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/60182026/12299030?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume this is what you wanted. Try this below code:

```
struct FadeView: View {
  @State var isClicked = false
  @State var text = "Faded Text"
  var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Text(text) //fade in and fade out
            .opacity(isClicked ? 0 : 1)
        Button("Click to animate") {
            withAnimation {
                isClicked.toggle()
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `withAnimation` function and manipulate the duration, options and delay

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var isActive = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Fade") {
                withAnimation(.easeIn(duration: 3.0).delay(2)){
                    isActive.toggle()
                }
            }
            
            Rectangle()
                .frame(width: 222.0, height: 222.0)
                .opacity(isActive ? 0 : 1)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a button I am trying to do this with text.  The old code was used on a Label with the text.

Comment: if you want to animate a text just change the Rectangle with text